# Saving files of a crashed workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, workspace

My workspace just crashed and I had a bunch of stuff done that I might not be able to remember everything. Is there a way, a file, something of my workspace that allows me to see what classes were opened? Maybe there's a file in my .metadata that stores what classes are opened.
Does anyone have any idea?

If you guys have any idea of how can I do it.. it's gonna be helpful!

Comment: Don't know but you could find more information on workspace\.metadata\.log

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is move your workspace to a new directory, ie workspace2, open eclipse and use the original workspace location.  This will create a brand new workspace.

Then you can import your projects from your corrupt workspace, now called workspace2, by right clicking on your navigator tab and importing.

Best of luck!

Comment: let me try it on :), do you have any idea if SVN will screw this up?

Comment: It shouldn't affect SVN.  You may have to do an update to head, but you won't loose any of your changes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, locate it and make a copy of it.  Then you can create a new workspace and import existing projects into it, then point to the root of the old workspace and let it find all the projects.  Then you should be up and running.   Save your changes!   Do not work in this workspace!

*Then* you can start a completely new workspace and populate it properly from scratch and work in that.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse stores the workspace state every 5 minutes. See Window > Preferences > General > Workspace ("Workspace save internal")

Eclipse keeps the last opened files, you can reopen them in the File menu at the bottom. By default, it stores the names of the last 4 files only. The maximum is 15. You can increase it from 4 to 15 and will immediately show 15 files in the File menu. See Window > Preferences > General > Editors ("Size of recently opened files"). The setting is stored in `\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs` in the key `RECENT_FILES`. Unfortunately, I have not found an easy way to see all the files at once.

The file `\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml` contains the state of the editors, e.g. the open files and the positions of the cursors for each file.

Eclipse keeps a history of the local files. See Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History. The actual files are stored in `\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history\`

You can see the local history per file if you select a file, open the context menu, click Compare With > Local History.